# Can't change the background behind a text, in which a video is playing inside it

Tags: html, css, video, text, tailwind-css

I have made a text inside which a video is playing. I can't change the background, behind the text, to something different that white color. I would like to add a photo as a background instead of white color. I am  using tailwind css. Does someone know how to do that?

```html
    <div class="container grid">
      <div
        class="absolute flex justify-center items-center overflow-hidden w-full h-screen"
      >
        <video
          class="absolute top-0 left-0 object-cover w-full h-full"
          autoplay
          muted
          loop
          src="../img/barber.mp4"
          type="video/mp4"
        ></video>
        <h1
          class="absolute top-0 left-0 text-[25vw] text-center text-[#000] leading-[100vh] bg-[#fff] mix-blend-screen w-full h-full"
        >
          BARBER
        </h1>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tailwind isn't intended to do *everything* CSS can do. It provides [color gradients](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/background-image), but it doesn't sound like that's what you want. Just use some custom styling to apply your [background image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image) to the heading element.

```html
<style>
h1.fancy-bg {
  background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/800);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
</style>

<div class="container grid">
  <div
    class="absolute flex justify-center items-center overflow-hidden w-full h-screen"
  >
    <video
      class="absolute top-0 left-0 object-cover w-full h-full"
      autoplay
      muted
      loop
      src="../img/barber.mp4"
      type="video/mp4"
    ></video>
    <h1
      class="absolute top-0 left-0 text-[25vw] text-center text-[#000] 
        leading-[100vh] bg-[#fff] mix-blend-screen w-full h-full fancy-bg"
    >
      BARBER
    </h1>
  </div>
</div>
```